# Any converter available to connect my android phone to an iPod/iPhone car dock?

Tags: car-dock

I have a iPod/iPhone car dock, which integrates into the back of my stereo as if it were a CD changer.  I'd like to hook my android phone up to it, but the only input is an iPod/iPhone cable (technically it is from pre-iPhone-3GS days, but I was using another adapter so my iPhone 3GS would charge on it).